# Problema con jquery Notice: Undefined index

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysqli, script

Buenas
Tengo una problema con los `combobox` y el **jquery**, no se "activa" el evento del menú desplegable(tengo 2 menús dependientes marca->modelo)

**script que esta en el head del html**

```
    <script language="javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("cbx_marca").change(function () {
            id_marca = $(this).val()
            $.ajax({
              type:"POST",
              url:"includes/getMarca.php", 
              data:{ id_marca: id_marca },
              success: function(data){
             $("cbx_modelo").html(data);
               }
             })
        })
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
       <form id="combo" name="combo" method="POST" action="guardar.php">
        
        <div>Seleccione la Marca: 
            <select id="cbx_marca" name="cbx_marca">
                <option value="0">Seleccionar Marca</option>
                
                <?php WHILE ($row=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                
                <option value="<?php echo $row["IdMarca"];?>"><?php echo 
               $row["NombreMarca"];?></option>
                
                <?php } ?>
            
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>Seleccione el Modelo: 
            <select id="cbx_modelo" name="cbx_modelo">
            </select>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" id="enviar" name="enviar" value="Guardar" />
    </form>
```

**El archivo getMarca**

```
   require ('../conexion.php');

  if ( !empty($_POST['id_marca'])) {
      $id_marca = (int)$_POST['id_marca'];
       }
        else{
         echo 'NO se recibieron datos POST';
           $id_marca = 2;
         }
       $query2 = "SELECT IdModelo, NombreModelo FROM modelo WHERE IdMarca = 
         '$id_marca' ORDER BY NombreModelo";
       $resultado2 = $mysqli->query($query2);

         $html= "<option value='0'>Seleccionar Modelo</option>";

while($row2 = $resultado2->fetch_assoc())
{
    $html.= "<option value='".$row2['IdModelo']."'>".$row2['NombreModelo']."</option>";
}

echo $html;
```

Con el `if` del getMarca, comprobé que no le llega el post y no sabría si es porque no se "activan" los eventos o estoy haciendo algo mal.

Disculpen mi ignorancia estoy estudiando aun y espero que me puedan ayudar.

> PD:Es la primera vez que utilizo esta pagina, si me falta algo o lo que sea, díganme.
>
> Ultima edicion y funcional

```
 <script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cbx_marca").change(function () {

        $("#cbx_marca option:selected").each(function () {
            id_marca = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                 type:"POST",
                 url:"includes/getMarca.php", 
                 data:{ id_marca: id_marca },
                 success: function(data){
                             $("#cbx_modelo").html(data);
                           }
                })            
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70644/discussion-on-question-by-enrique-menendez-problema-con-jquery-notice-undefined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realiza la petición del `script` del `head` así:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#cbx_marca").change(function () {

            $("#cbx_marca option:selected").each(function () {
                id_marca = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                     type:"POST",
                     url:"includes/getMarca.php", 
                     data:{ id_marca: id_marca },
                     success: function(data){
                                 $("#cbx_modelo").html(data);
                               }
                    })            
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: >Lo probe asi y nada               

       <script language="javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#cbx_marca").change(function () {

                $.ajax({
                  type:"POST",
                  url:"includes/getMarca.php", 
                  data:{ id_marca: id_marca },
                  success: function(data){
                 $("#cbx_modelo").html(data);
                   }
                 })
            })
        });
    </script>

Comment: pero te faltan cosas ahi,  te voy a actualizar la respuesta con todo lo que tienes que poner

Comment: ya te lo edite, prueba ahora, es que te faltaban cosas

Comment: Al menos en teoría, lo que tiene OP y esta solución son equivalentes (`$.post` es un _alias_ para `$.ajax` de tipo POST), por lo que el resultado debería ser similar.

Comment: si , pero como veo que le da error en cuestiones de esperar resultados de la petición, por eso le pedí que realizara esta vía , en aras de que le solucionara el error

Comment: @Travv ahora me esta funcionando, seguire trabando para ver como progresa

Comment: y utilizaste los cambios que te di en la respuesta?

Comment: @Travv si si me sirvio lo tuyo, disculpa que no tenga para darte puntos o algo en al pagina, me registre apenas hoy. Pero muchísimas gracias enserio!

Comment: no te preocupes, aquí estamos para ayudar , lo que quiera saber si esa era la solución para saber si estaba en lo correcto. Saludos

Comment: exacto , por eso le dije que cambiara el modo de la petición, así solucionar el problema, y que tuviera mas claro el como hacer la petición y que era cada dato que tenia

Answer (score 0):

Voy a proponer esta solución (parcial), ya que en tu código persisten ciertas incoherencias. Por ejemplo, si no hay id_marca en la petición, tú estableces que su valor sea `2` y al mismo tiempo haces un `echo` diciendo que no se posteó un id_marca.

La petición Ajax no manejaba un método `fail` que te avise si hay un error, por ejemplo, en la url del archivo.

Las consultas SQL son vulnerables. Una vez resuelto el problema principal te propondré una solución segura en ese sentido.

Se puede optimizar el manejo de la consulta y sus resultados, por ejemplo, si arroja cero filas, etc.

También, estoy implementando código jQuery actualizado, usando `function`, así como `done` en lugar de `success`.

Hice otras mejoras al código. Prueba y comenta los resultados.

### jQuery

```
$(function() {

    $('#cbx_marca').on('change', function() {
        var id_marca = $(this).val();
        var data= { id_marca: id_marca };
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/getMarca.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'html'
        });

        request.done(function(respuesta) {
            console.log(respuesta);
            $("#cbx_modelo").html(respuesta);                            
            
        });
        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("Hubo un error: " + textStatus);
        });


    })
});
```

---

### `getMarca.php`

```
require ('../conexion.php');

if (isset($_POST['id_marca'])) 
{
    $id_marca = (int)$_POST['id_marca'];
}else{
    //echo 'NO se recibieron datos POST'; //???
    $id_marca = 2; //????
}
$query2 = "SELECT IdModelo, NombreModelo FROM modelo WHERE IdMarca = ? ORDER BY NombreModelo";
$resultado2 = $mysqli->query($query2);

$html= '<option value="0">Seleccionar Modelo</option>';

while($row2 = $resultado2->fetch_assoc())
{
    $html.= '<option value='"'.$row2["IdModelo"].'"'>'.$row2["NombreModelo"].'</option>';
}

echo $html;
```

Comment: falta hacer el _bind_ para IdMarca.

Comment: Lo probe y funciona!
En la consola js, me aparece esto "Conexión exitosa!<option value="0">Seleccionar Modelo</option><option value='5'>Ford 1</option><option value='6'>Ford 2</option>" me dice lo que esta trayendo no?

Comment: Correcto @EnriqueMenendez, ahora sería cuestión de añadir la respuesta a un elemento válida del HTML y se actualizarán los datos. Ahora tendrás que revisar lo de la consulta, ya que el código como está ahora es vulnerable.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro no puse nada relativo al `bind` porque no implementé consultas preparadas en la respuesta. La idea era primero hacer que el código funcione.

Answer (score 0):

Un poco tarde, pero acabo de ver el problema de tu [código original](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/126471/1). Tenías esto:

```
$.post("includes/getMarca.php", { id_marca: id_marca }, function(data){ 
   $("#cbx_modelo").html(data); 
});
```

Pero ¿qué es `"includes/getMarca.php"`? ¿o `{ id_marca: id_marca }`? ¿o la función del final? **Te faltaba poner los parámetros del `$.post` de manera correcta (con un nombre y entre llaves {}**.

Lo correcto habría sido como se especifica en la [documentación de jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/):

```
$.post({
   url: "includes/getMarca.php", 
   data: { id_marca: id_marca }, 
   success: function(data){ 
       $("#cbx_modelo").html(data); 
   }
});
```

La solución de Travv funciona porque pone bien los nombres de los parámetros en `$.ajax`. Si los hubieses puesto igual te habría funcionado porq `$.post` es equivalente a `$.ajax` con POST.

Comment: No me habia dado cuenta, muchas gracias tambien!!